# Visualize continuous sequence of "blocks" as rectangular layout

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a continuous sequence of "units" of several types (I will call them "blocks" here), described in the table, for example:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T,text='
 Group  nA  nB  nC
 Group1  2   3   1
 Group2  1   4   2
 Group3  1   5   2
 Group4  4   2   2
 Group5  6   6   2
           ')
```

i.e. 2 blocks of type `A`, then 3 blocks of type `B`, 1 block of type `C`, etc. I would like to visualize it by a sort of rectangular map (if you have ever seen a map of harddrive sectors, for example).
In a semigraphics it would look like that:

```
AABBBC ABBBBCC ABBB
BBCC AAAABBCC AAAAA
ABBBBBBCC
```

Here I left spaces between groups, but in fact it would be a continuous sequence (to display a border between groups would be great, but not critical) that goes in the "row" of the plot and just wraps to the next row when full.
And the ultimate result I want to get would be something like this:
[image]
(there is probably some name for that type of visualization - feel free to edit the title)
I understand there will be no off-the-shelf solution, but if you could suggest at least a direction I should look - that would be great already. I describe this sample in `R`, but don't mind other tools (`d3.js`-based would be cool for example)

tmp UPD. based on the answer of PoGibas, just a little addition to make it "wrap":

```
size1 <- 17L
df2$row <- ceiling(df2$X / size1)
df2$pos <- df2$X - df2$row*size1
ggplot(df2, aes(pos, row, fill = L)) +
  geom_tile(color = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "red")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_reverse()
```

Comment: So first line should go "AABBBC"?

Comment: First group is "AABBBC", then it continues (in the same "row" of the plot) by the  second group, etc. It's a continuous sequence (I added space between groups only to make it easier to understand) that wraps to the next "row" when it reaches the margin of the plot. I will add this to the text of the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to "expand" original data (`df1`). For this we can use `rep` - repeat entry *n*  times.

```
# Create matrix of entries
M <- t(matrix(LETTERS[1:3], 5, 3, byrow = TRUE))
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
# [2,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
# [3,] "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C" 

# Repeat entry in matrix M by transposed original matrix
df2 <- data.frame(L = rep(M, t(df1[, 2:4])))
# Add position on x axis
df2$X <- 1:nrow(df2)
# head(df2)
#   L X
# 1 A 1
# 2 A 2
# 3 B 3
# 4 B 4
# 5 B 5
# 6 C 6

# Plot using geom_tile
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(X, 0, fill = L)) +
    geom_tile(color = NA) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "red")) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Povilas! (I will keep the question open for a while, maybe someone can suggest how to make the plot "wrap" to multiple lines. In my case, the total number of groups is too high, so it's hard to make it visible in one line)

Comment: @VasilyA how long is the line? I didn't understand from the question.

Comment: well ideally I wanted it to be flexible, i.e. depend on the size of the plot (so that it would adapt to the changes of Plot Zoom window of RStudio, for example). But it's probably unrealistic, so for now I just added a hardcoded size of the line. See the update in the question, that gives a perfect plot just as I needed. Could you add it to your answer?